# How to refactor duplicated code in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring

I'm currently working on refactoring a lot of duplicated code in a couple of `UserControl`s in Windows Forms project.

The architecture leaves much to be desired with a lot of logic implemented inside the UI layer. This will be fixed eventually, I'm now working on improving what I have on my hands now.

The problem is, that a lot of duplicated code relates directly to controls, for instance:

```
private void InitDestinationPathControls(string path)
{
  if (someField)
  {
    tbOne.Enabled = false;
    tbOne.Visible = false;
    btnTwo.Enabled = false;
    btnTwo.Visible = false;
    tbOne.Text = string.Empty;
    return;
  }
  // (...)
}
```

Don't get too attached to the cited code itself, it is just an example.

I'd like to move this code to a common base class, but it relies directly on specific fields (even though they are exactly the same in all controls too). Those fields, on the other hand, are generated by the designer, so I cannot extract them to the base class.

The only thing that comes to my mind is to pass those fields as parameters to a method in base class, but then if some method uses a lot of them, I'll end up with a monstrous interface part and that won't actually improve the readability too much.

How can I deal with such common parts of user controls in Windows Forms?

Comment: It seems something and more code are missing. A method in a root class rings true, else did you try a helper class having extension methods?

Comment: Those enabled/visible/text settings can be databound properties in whatever underlying business object. In fact, nothing stops you to use MVVM even a WinForms application. [Here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.ComponentModelDemo) is a demo app, which uses the same ViewModel in a WinForms and in a WPF GUI. And [here](https://github.com/koszeggy/KGySoft.Drawing.Tools/blob/master/KGySoft.Drawing.DebuggerVisualizers.Test/ViewModel/DebuggerTestFormViewModel.cs) is another (somewhat simpler) ViewModel example of a form with some `...Enabled` properties.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have a combination of several controls that appears in several forms. In other words: you have for instance some buttons, comboboxes, etc, that you want to show on different forms, and you want them to have the same behaviour.

If not only the behaviour of these controls is the same on all forms, but also the layout, then consider to create a class derived from UserControl.

The UserControl hides from the outside world which controls are shown, how they are visualized and how they behave.

I assume that you already pulled the model out of the visualisation of the data.

If all instances of this user control should all call the same functions of possibly a different object of the same class, then give your special user control a property that represents this class, or at least an interface. During construction you can plug in the actual class that should handle the actions after operator input.

If, on the other hand, the layout differs on each form, but the collection of buttons, comboboxes, etc and their behaviour is similar on all forms that show this collection of controls and they have a lot of common behaviour, consider to create your own ControlCollection.

For instance, if on several forms you have a button to select a (text) file, labels with the name, size and creation date of the selected file, and an edit box that shows the content of the text file, but you want to layout them differently, consider something like this:

```
class FileDisplayControls : IDisposable
{
    public Button ButtonSelectFile {get;} = new Button();
    public Label labelFileName {get; } = new Label();
    public Label labelFileSize {get; } = new Label();
    public TextBox textFileContents {get; } = new FileContents();

    private void ButtonSelectFile_Clicked(object sender, ...)
    {
        // TODO: open file dialog, display result in labels and text box
    }
}
```

Constructor can set initial layout properties of the controls, and subscribe to events, such that the controls will react on user input.

The user of the class (= code, not operator) immediately has a collection of controls that have some standard behaviour, like react on button click. All he has to do is set the location of the items in his own form. If desired change other layout properties (colour, background) and put them on his own form.

If you want to prevent that others change other visual aspects of the controls than the position, don't publish the control themselves, only the position of the control:

```
public System.Drawing.Point LocationSelectFileButton
{
    get => this.buttonSelectFile.Location;
    set => this.buttonSelectFile.Location = value;
}

public System.Drawing.Point LocationFileContentTextBox
{
    get => this.textBoxFileContent.Location;
    set => this.textBoxFileContent.Location = value;
}
```

etc.

If needed, you can add events for users:

```
public event EventHandler SelectedFileChanged;

public string FileName => this.labelFileName.Text;
public string FileContents => this.textBoxFileContent.Text;
```

etc.

### Conclusion

The solution that you choose depends on the similarity between the controls on the various forms:

- if Behaviour and Layout are all the same: UserControl
- If only position and a few properties different: special class with the properties that are different. This way you can force a more similar style: all "Select File" buttons look similar.
- If only one or two behaviours are different: add `Action<...>` properties or events
- If you want full control of the layout: expose the Controls.
- The behaviour that is common for all you forms that show these controls (in my example: how to select a file and what to do when a file is selected) is inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

repeated code can be extracted to method (possibly in base class, or as static method in helper class)

```
public void DisableControls(params Control[] controls)
{
    foreach(var c in Controls)
    {
        c.Enabled = false;
        c.Visible = false;
        if (c is TextBox t)
        {
            t.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}

private void InitDestinationPathControls(string path)
{
     if (someField)
     {
        DisableControls(tbOne, btnTwo);
        return;
     }

     // (...)
}
```